# PHP5.4+PHPExcel+IIS = Битый файл

Tags: php, excel, iis, windows-server, phpexcel

У меня на машине локально запущен IIS-сервер. В нем крутится проект. При экспорте данных из проекта в excel ни каких проблем не возникает.

Перенес проект на Windows Server 2008 SP2 x64, IIS 7. Экспортирую файл, приходит. Открываю - excel ссылается на битый формат, вылазят кракозябры.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 1. Сравните файлы; 2. Поищите ошибки в логах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызов `ob_end_clean()` перед записью в файл решил все проблемы.